# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'start' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a list like this one which contains over 1000 entries.

```
[
    {
        "start": "Sun May 24 2015 01:00:00 GMT+0530 (IST)",
        "end": "Sun May 24 2015 01:30:00 GMT+0530 (IST)",
        "title": "Event 1"
    },
    {
        "start": "Sun May 24 2015 04:00:00 GMT+0530 (IST)",
        "end": "Sun May 24 2015 06:00:00 GMT+0530 (IST)",
        "title": "Event 2"
    }
]
```

and i'am writing a function like this one :-

```
function finalIndex(ind)
        {   
            var final_ind = ind+1;
            var chkdate = new Date(list[ind].start);
            var day = chkdate.getDate();
            //alert(day);
            var chkdate1 = new Date(list[final_ind].start);
            var day1 = chkdate.getDate();
            //alert(day1);
            final_ind = final_ind+1;
            while(day == day1)
            {   
                chkdate1 = new Date(list[final_ind].start);
                day1 = chkdate.getDate();
                final_ind = final_ind+1;
            }
            final_ind = final_ind-1;
            return final_ind;
        }
```

In this function **ind** is the starting index of given date and with the help of this function i want to find out the index of final object associated with given date.

The commented alerts outside while are working fine and shows 24,24 as output.

But i'm getting  **Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'start' of undefined** inside the while loop although it is able to read the list[final_ind].start befor loop.

Comment: `final_ind = final_ind+1;` will cause the `final_ind` inside the while loop to be different than the `final_ind` outside the while loop. This could cause the array lookup to return undefined.

Comment: didn't got you...??? and i am getting error at chkdate1 = new Date(list[final_ind].start); inside while loop.

Comment: `final_ind = final_ind+1;`
            `while(day == day1)`
            `{   chkdate1 = new Date(list[final_ind].start);`

Comment: i'm just incrementing the var final_ind

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change from:

```
while(day == day1)
```

to:

```
while(day == day1 && list[final_ind])
```

or:

```
while(day == day1 && list.length > final_ind)
```

**Explanation**:

The last loop go out off bounds, adding this you sure the object exists.

Comment: now the error is gone but now the while loop goes on till the end although i have only 10 entries with date = 24;

Comment: to get your desired result, change the line inside loop `day1 = chkdate.getDate();` to `day1 = chkdate1.getDate();`.

Comment: HeartBeat is right, I didn't see that on first look.

Answer (score 0):

When your function runs on the last index, your `final_ind = ind+1` assigns a non-existent index, and when it gets to `chkdate1=new Date(list[final_ind].start)` it throws an error because that item doesn't exist. Avoid that by checking that you're on the last item by adding this line as the first one of your function: `if(ind >= list.length-1) return`.

---

Anyway. I was reading your code and personally I think that you need to re-think and re-write what you are trying to achieve. It doesn't make much sense and there's a lot of redundancy.

Comment: Well You can suggest better ways to do it. that would be great help to beginners like me.

Comment: I know my friend. I wanted to answer the question but found too much. I didn't have time to suggest that much but to re-think that one. Hope someone can help you more. Right now I'm in a rush :( Sorry about that.